# Letting smart pointers delete SDL components in a specific order

Tags: c++, sdl, smart-pointers

Ok, so basically, I have an SDL wrapper header called SDL_Video_wrapper.h. It contains two wrapper classes : `CWindowWrap`, and `CRendererWrap` in a namespce called `detail`. The user can access those classes via two shared pointers, defined as the following :

```
 using CWindow = std::shared_ptr<detail::CWindowWrap>;//types Here are hidden from the user ! 
 using CRenderer = std::shared_ptr<detail::CRendererWrap>;
```

And the users can create those shared_ptrs with this two methods :

```
 CWindow construct_window(Window_properties p){
    if (has_init_SDL_Video){
        return std::make_shared<detail::CWindowWrap>(p.title, p.xPos, p.yPos, p.width, p.height, p.flags);
     }
     else
        LOG("SDL_Wrapper", "Cannot construct Window : SDL hasn't been initialized !");
        return nullptr;
 }
```

and it's basically the same with my Renderer;vy

I have another function called QUIT_All_Subsystems, which shuts down everything in SDL.

SO, the problem is that I need my smart pointers to dispose **automatically** **after** Quit_All_Subsytems is called ( I automatically call it with `atexit(Quit_All_Subsystem)` )

Comment: If you're registering `Quit_All_Subsystem` with `atexit()`, then it means your program will shutdown after it's been called. Your `shared_ptr` will be automatically released in this case. Are you looking for a way to release them in the case `Quit_All_Subsystem` is called before the program's exit?

Comment: No, no; I would like to call them **before** Quit is called; it doesn't matters when quit is called !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the shared pointer destructor here with an example provided: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr/

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please specify what is your problem?

Comment: Also, another problem that came up was that the destructor was called twice by the shared pointers; it's not a problem, it' just weird !

Comment: Do note that as it's a `shared_ptr`, calling its destructor **does not guarantee the pointee will be destroyed**. Indeed, some part of the code may store a copy of this `shared_ptr`, and if this copy still exists when you call `Quit_All_Subsystem`, then the pointee won't be destroyed, only the `shared_ptr`.